# React/Redux, Redux store changes but does not immediately render items without leaving the page and returning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, render

> When I clicked on the button "Buy", the store redux is updated and
>   push a new array to the initial state. But I don't see any new render
>   in the shop-cart section without leaving the page and go in again so I
>   can see new items. I'm new to React and Redux, I have been trying to fix it but it was not working and i'm very confused about it

Here is the reducer section

```
const initialState = {
    counter : 0,
    cartData : [
      {
         id : 1,
         name : "Melon", 
         price : 100,
         img : "https://d1hr6nb56yyl1.cloudfront.net/product-images/93368-280.jpg",
         quantity : 1
     },
       {
         id : 1,
         name : "Melon", 
         price : 100,
         img : "https://d1hr6nb56yyl1.cloudfront.net/product-images/93368-280.jpg",
         quantity : 1
     },
    ]   
};

 function cartNumber(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log(state.cartData)
    let cartIndex = [...state.cartData];
    switch(action.type){
        case "INCREMENT" :
         return {
            ...state,
            cartData : cartIndex.concat(action.newData)
         };
         break;
        case "DECREMENT" :
        default : 
            return state; 
    }
    return cartIndex
}
export default cartNumber;
```

Here is the Item Detail page and Items Cart section

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from "react"; 
import SubCart from "../components/SubCart";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";


function ItemDetail({match, history}){

        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const [item, setItem] = useState({});



        const scroll = () => {window.scroll(0,0)};

        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchItem = async () => {
            const fetchItem = await fetch(
                `https://5e5a9fc26a71ea0014e61f04.mockapi.io/api/${match.params.category}/${match.params.id}`
            ); 

            const item = await fetchItem.json();
            setItem(item);
        };
            fetchItem();
            scroll();
        }, [])

        const showRating = (rating) => {
            var result = []; 
            for(var i = 1; i <= rating; i++){
                result.push(<i className="fa fa-star" key={i + 1} style={{fontSize : ".8rem", color : "#ff4e00", padding : "0rem .1rem"}}></i>);
            }
            for (var j = 1; j <= (5-rating); j++) {
                result.push(<i className="far fa-star" key={i + 1} style={{fontSize : ".8rem", padding : "0rem .1rem"}}></i>);
            }
        return result;
    }

    const backButton = () => {
        history.goBack();
    }


    const showSubcart = () => {
          let sub = document.getElementById("subcart-section");
          let bg = document.getElementById("bg-ccc");

          sub.classList.toggle("showSubCart");
          bg.classList.toggle("bg-ccc");
          dispatch({type : "INCREMENT", newData : item });            
    }

    return (

        <div style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}>
            <div className="item-detail" style={{paddingBottom : "1rem"}}>
                <div className="section-heading"> 
                    <div className="section-content">
                        <div className="icon-home">
                            <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
                        </div> 
                        <div className="nav-home">
                            <Link to="/">Home</Link> 
                        </div>
                        <div className="icon-to"> 
                            <i className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        </div> 
                        <div className="nav-cart"> 
                            <Link to="/">{item.category}</Link> 
                        </div>   
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div className="img-detail"> 
                    <img src={item.img} alt={item.name} /> 
                    <span className="icon-section"><i className="far fa-heart"></i></span> 
                    <span className="icon-section-arrow" onClick={() => backButton()}><i className="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></span> 
                </div> 
                <div className="item-detail-content"> 
                    <div className="container"> 
                        <Link to="/" style={{color : "black"}}><span className="category">{item.category}</span></Link> 
                        <div><h2>{item.name}</h2></div>  
                        <div><h3>{item.price}$</h3></div>  
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>{showRating(item.rating)} <span style={{fontSize : ".8rem"}}>(210)</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> 

                        <div className="buy" onClick={() => showSubcart()}> 
                            <span className="buy-text">Buy</span> 
                            <span className="buy-icon"><i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="description">
                            <div className="head-description">
                                <h3><i className="far fa-bookmark"></i> Description</h3> 
                            </div>
                            <div className="body-description"> 
                                <p>...</p> 
                            </div> 
                        </div>  
                        <div className="infoPolicy mt-top">
                            <div className="box-head">
                                <i className="fas fa-truck"></i>
                            </div> 
                            <div className="box-content"> 
                                <p className="note-p">FREE NATIONAL DELIVERY</p><span className="note">(Products over 50$)</span>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <div className="infoPolicy mt-top">
                            <div className="box-head">
                            <i className="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>                     
                        </div> 
                            <div className="box-content"> 
                                <p className="note-p">Returns are Easy</p><span className="note">(Return 30days for items)</span>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <div className="infoPolicy mt-top mt-bt">
                            <div className="box-head">
                                <i className="fas fa-headset"></i>
                            </div> 
                            <div className="box-content"> 
                                <p className="note-p">Telephone consultation</p><span className="note">(Free from 8:00 - 21:00 every day)</span>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>  
                </div> 
                <SubCart />
            </div> 
        </div>

    );
}

export default ItemDetail;
```

```
import React, {useState} from "react"; 
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux"; 

function ItemCart(){

    let data = useSelector(state => state.cartData);

    let [items, setItem] = useState(data);

    return (
            <div className="subcart-link"> 
                {items.map((item, index) => (
                    <div className="d-flex" key={index}>
                        <div className="subcart-img"> 
                            <img src={item.img} alt="pubg"/> 
                        </div> 
                        <div className="subcart-item-content"> 
                                <Link to="/">{item.name}</Link> 
                                <div className="subcart-item-detail"> 
                                    <p>{item.price}$<span className="subcart-quantity">x 2</span></p> 
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="delete-click"> 
                            <p>x</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                ))} 
            </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at your `ItemCart` you are duplicating redux state into a react state, which is not advisable. they are two different entities, though you can have both types at your application a given specific state should be handled by a specific state manager.

at your `ItemCart` remove `useState` altogether, and map over `data` variable instead. your issue comes from the fact that your `items` state inherits only the original redux state, but since they are different states, it doesnt get updated when redux state changes.

fwiw, dont use dom manipulation to handle classes like you do at `showSubCart`, this is not good. I suggest to use some boolean logic instead to toggle class, based on some props or state value.

Comment: You are my Hero !!. Thanks, u so much. Thanks for your advice and I have been a success to fix it. Thank you